# MSVCRT enter key bug?

Tags: python, msvcrt

Basically, I am playing around with the `msvcrt` library in Python, and my code is giving me weird results. When I have a 'getch' string that is the enter key ('\r') returned from a function, my main `while` loop automatically picks the returned ('\r') variable as a keyboard entry from the user. It triggers the unwanted condition of breaking the `while` loop as if the user had hit the enter key. Can someone please explain what I'm not seeing?

```
import msvcrt

def test():
    while True:
        if msvcrt.kbhit():
            a = msvcrt.getch().decode('ASCII')
            break
    return a

uiStr = ''
newStr = ''
while True:
    if msvcrt.kbhit():
        toFunc = msvcrt.getch().decode('ASCII')
        if (toFunc=='\r'): #this condition gets activated if return var from last loop is '\r'
            break
        elif toFunc.isalpha()==True:
            newStr = test()  #If '\r' is passed from function, it activates the kbhit condition in the next loop iteration
            uiStr += newStr
        else:
            uiStr += toFunc
        print(uiStr)
```